# Efficient grouping by key using mapPartitions or partitioner in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, grouping, partition

So, I have a data like the following,

```
[ (1, data1), (1, data2), (2, data3), (1, data4), (2, data5) ]
```

which I want to convert to the following, for further processing.

```
[ (1, [data1, data2, data4]), (2, [data3, data5]) ]
```

I used groupByKey and reduceByKey, but due to really large amount of data it fails. The data is not tall but wide. In other words, keys are from 1 upto 10000, but, value list ranges from 100k to 900k.

I am struggling with this issue and plan to apply `mapPartitions` or `(Hash)partitioner`.

So, if one of these may work, I'd like to know

1. Using `mapPartions`, could you please give some code snippet?
2. Using `(Hash)partitioner`, could you please give some example how to control partitions by some element like key.. e.g. is there a way to create each partition based on key (i.e. 1,2,.. above) with no need to shuffle.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 9 (flatMap at TSUMLR.scala:209) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 1
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:542)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:538)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:538)
        at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 6):

None of the proposed method would work. Partitioner by definition have to shuffle the data and will suffer from the same limitations as `groupByKey`. `mapPartitions` cannot move data to another partition so it is completely useless. Since your description of the problem is rather vague it is hard to give a specific advice but in general I would try following steps:

- try to rethink the problem. Do you really need all the values at once? How do you plan to utilize these? Can you obtain the same results without collecting to a single partition?
- is it possible to reduce the traffic? How many unique values do you expect? Is it possible to compress the data before the shuffle (for example count values or use RLE)?
- consider using larger executors. Spark has to keep in memory only the values for a single key and can spill processed keys to disk.
- split your data by key:

  ```
  val keys =  rdd.keys.distinct.collect
  val rdds = keys.map(k => rdd.filter(_._1 == k))
  ```

  and process each RDD separatelly.

Comment: You're advice is really great! ) It's really helpful.